# DataGridView select multiple columns

Tags: c#

This seems like it should be simple, but I am not finding a good answer.

I have a DataGridView that is populated from a DataTable.  I want the user to be able to export it in Excel.  However, the dgv has 20 columns and in my export, I just want to copy the first 5 columns.

I would imagine something like this `dgv.Columns[0, 4].Select();` should work, but it does not.

So far, I have just done `dgv.SelectAll();` and copied that to the clipboard, then dumped the whole thing in Excel, finally deleting columns 6-20.  It just feels inelegant, and I figure there has to be a better answer.

Comment: I do not think there is a mechanism in the `DataGridView` that allows you to programmatically set a “group” of cells to "selected". However, a simple loop(s) may provide a way to “select” individual cells like… `dataGridView1[colIndex, rowIndex].Selected = true;` Obviously you will need to have the grid’s `MultiSelect` property set to `true` and most likely have the grid’s selection mode set to `CellSelect` or `RowHeaderSelect` should also work.

Comment: How do you create the xl file? The code? Selecting the first 5 columns data shouldn't be an issue. [Example](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/hrojasara/export-datagridview-to-excel-in-C-Sharp/).

Comment: I usually copy the data table to a new table.  Then delete columns not needed.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I was trying to avoid loops, which was why I was trying to pull from the datagridview instead of the source datatable. 

My code is pretty straightforward:
            dg.SelectAll();

            DataObject dataObj = dg.GetClipboardContent();
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj);
then I paste it:
Excel.Worksheet ws
Excel.Range range = (Excel.Range)ws.Cells[1, 1];
ws.PasteSpecial(range, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);

Answer (score 0):

Sure, use something like EPPlus to generate an excel file directly. It can load from a datatable

```
using var p = new ExcelPackage(...);
var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("...");
ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);
p.Save();
```

Simplest way to dump everything except the first 5 columns would probably be to Copy() it (or modify the original if you're done with it) and jettison the 6+ index columns (`while(dt.Columns.Count>5) dt.Columns.RemoveAt(5);`)

Comment: I am not sure if my work will let me use EPPlus, but it looks intriguing.  Thank you.  I will check it out and see if I can use it.